# AVAssetReaderTrackOutput sometimes delivers blank video frames

Tags: macos, cocoa, video

I'm writing an application that reads a video file using AVKit, and does something to each frame, finally producing an output image.

First I load the asset, with the `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` set to `YES`, then I find the first video track, and create an asset reader and an asset reader output with the decompression settings set to `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` - according to the docs this is one of the few allowed values here.

Then I call `copyNextSampleBuffer` in a loop, and do the following with the resulting `CMSampleBufferRef`:

```
CVImageBufferRef movieFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
NSCIImageRep *imageRep = [NSCIImageRep 
  imageRepWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:movieFrame]];

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep size]];
[image addRepresentation:imageRep];
```

For the most part, this works fine. However there are some videos that generate the occasional blank frame, and yet others for which every frame is blank. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this one eventually. The occasional blank frames were due to a threading issue, and the always blank frames were solved by using the following to create the NSImage:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(movieFrame,0);
uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(movieFrame);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(movieFrame);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(movieFrame);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(movieFrame);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress,
                                                width, height, 8,
                                                bytesPerRow,
                                                colorSpace, 
                                      kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little |
                                      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
CGImageRef frame = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(movieFrame,0);
CGContextRelease(newContext);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:frame size:NSMakeSize(width,height)];

CGImageRelease(frame);
```

I wish I understood why, but at least it works now.